# ASP. NET Core model validation and Angular client side validation

Tags: angular, validation, asp.net-core-webapi, generator, openapi

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, and using validation attributes on the model classes (model: the API input parameter classes). I get automatic validation responses 400 out of the box, with full featured error information.

The client application will be an Angular 14 app.

There are more than a hundred model classes, with literally 1000 annotated properties, it would be great to not implement the very same redundantly at the Angular side...

**Question**

Is there any way, code generator, etc to get the very same validation behavior on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use https://github.com/jnwltr/swagger-angular-generator, which allows generation of API client libraries, forms services and documentation automatically given an swagger definition file. This takes advantage of some of your annotations from api to create all the types in typescript and forms services with validation.

Comment: Many thx, it is not clear, exactly what annotation can go through via OpenAPI json. (I mean what validation metainfo can possibly in the .json, based on OpenAPI schema?)

Comment: Check this article I wrote: https://blog.josematos.work/use-auto-generated-client-code-to-consume-your-api-from-an-angular-app-363c64f6c83a.